# Node / Express App .. how can i send GET & POST requests without redirect

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, asynchronous

Guys i'm new to node/express and i'm building app using express and there is a button i wanna click to save my data into database (MongoDB) .. but i don't want to have this request on specific end-point .. i mean i wanna send data to MongoDB without refresh or redirect the page .. and also after storing data in MongoDB i wanna server to notify me in the same page that its done successfully .. what can i use for that .. i hope u got my point and thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could send [XMLHttpRequests](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest) or use the [fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) on your front end.

Or you could opt into external libraries such as [Axios](https://github.com/axios/axios) or [jQuery's ajax](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

Comment: Another good option is axios https://github.com/axios/axios

Comment: Don't forget jQuery's AJAX: https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Answer (score 0):

in your button there's an event called onClick, that will be triggered when user click it, on that event you gonna send an HTTP request ( there's many ways to send it but I recommend you to use Axios)

```
   const axios = require('axios');
   const sendData = (userFirstName,userLastName)=>{
  axios.post('/operation', {
   firstName: userFirstName,      // pass your data as object
   lastName: userLastName 
 })
 .then(function (response) {
   // here will be the call back when request sent with success
  // so you can do your stuff
   console.log(response);
 })
 .catch(function (error) {
 // if the request failed for some reason , you can show something to user
   console.log(error);
 });

}
```

`<button onClick={()=>{sendData('John','Doe')}}> send data to express route </button>`

and in your express backend application, you should have an endpoint (API) with name `operation` in our example that will receive your Axios data and do the needed work with database

axios : https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios

onClick event : https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onclick.asp